# SQL appending tables with a massive number of columns

Tags: sql

I wish to append to a table new data that comes in from one table, which has a massive number of columns (i.e. hundreds) to a second. My understanding is that for an update on SQL, an update should specify fields. How can I:

1. append any new records from a query on a second table.
2. Ignore any clashes or existing records.

Doing this in hive. Basically Databricks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different ways handling this.)

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to append to a table new data that comes in from one table, which has a massive number of columns (i.e. hundreds) to a second.

> Ignore any clashes or existing records.

To append to a table new data that comes in from one table, which has a massive number of columns (i.e. hundreds) to a second in Hive, ignoring any clashes or existing records, you can do the next:

1/ You need to create a temporary table to store the new records from the second table.

2/ Then you should insert the new records from the second table into the temporary table.

3/And finally you need to merge the temporary table with the first table, using the INSERT OVERWRITE statement.

For example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_reports AS
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE created_at >= '2012-03-02';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE reports
PARTITION (user_id)
SELECT *
FROM new_reports;
```

In this example, the sql query appends new records from the users table to the reports table, ignoring any clashes or existing records.

That is it.

I hope it can help you.